# Add base map to animation Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, animation

I want to make an animation of fires using MCD64A1 with a base map something similar to [this Sentinel 5-P animation:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRkdG.gif)

[image]

What I could make until now using this code is:

```js
// Define a collection
var col = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MCD64A1').filterDate('2019-01-01', '2020-12-31').select('BurnDate')

// Define a mask to clip the data by.
var mask = ee.FeatureCollection('USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017')
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('wld_rgn', 'South America'));

print(mask);

// Add outline to the Map as a layer.
Map.centerObject(mask, 3);
Map.addLayer(mask);  

// Define the regional bounds of animation frames.
var region =  
    ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-86.88829713135783, 12.937849176033298],
          [-86.88829713135783, -30.715685432081326],
          [-30.81407838135783, -30.715685432081326],
          [-30.81407838135783, 12.937849176033298]]], null, false);


print('Region', region) 

// Define RGB visualization parameters.
var visParams = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 366,
  palette: ['FF0000']
};


// Create RGB visualization images for use as animation frames.
var rgbVis = col.map(function(img) {
  return img.visualize(visParams).clip(mask);
});

// Define GIF visualization parameters.
var gifParams = {
  'region': region,
  'dimensions': 600,
  'crs': 'EPSG:3857',
  'framesPerSecond': 5
};


// Print the GIF URL to the console.
print(rgbVis.getVideoThumbURL(gifParams));
```

which gives the following result:

[image: Fires]

I didn't find a way to do it.

Comment: Did you tried this?
It worked?
I have the same question..

Comment: Yes the answer works!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to add an image in the background and then display your red classified pixels on top of it. It seems like the image uses a DEM, you could for example pick the SRTM DEM in the GEE.

Play around with the visible parameters to get a nice visualization:

```
// define the background map variables
var srtmParams = {
  min: -13000,
  max: 15000,
  gamma: 1,
};

// Set the for south-america clipped SRTM image as background
var srtm = SRTM.clipToCollection(mask);
var srtmVis = srtm.visualize(srtmParams);
Map.addLayer(srtmVis)
```

Then use the `blend()` function to display your classified images on top of the background. Use the `paint()` function to display a featurecollection on top of an image.

```
// Create RGB visualization images for use as animation frames.
var rgbVis = col.map(function(img) {
  return srtmVis
        .paint(mask, srtmParams.max, 2) // max value will be presented in white
        .blend(img.visualize(visParams).clipToCollection(mask));
});
```

[Link to the complete code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/5dec4151a0298409a4b8947e5e78bb89)